# Mentain SQLITE Connection without open them for 1000 times. *WITHOUT OPEN AND CLOSE AFTER USING*

Tags: java, database, sqlite, connection, minecraft

I created a database for my Minecraft Server, in Java. I use Java 8, but i want to know how can i mentain SQLITE Connection Opened during server is running.

When i start server, connection be opened and when i close, connection be closed.

Problem is, my code is using PreparedStatements who acces connection any time when i want create statement.

My code is : https://hastebin.com/ahinidikev.java

How can i do use Only 1 connection and use preparedstatement just from this connection, not others?

And please, a code exemple, is more easy to understand for me.

*I got error: SQLITE Database is closed, who is reproduced because i use 2 connectons async at same time, that why i need mentain connection*

Comment: I think you need to show some code to understand better your problem

Comment: Just tell me how to create connection and mentain them opened and use prepare statements from that connection, without make another connections.

Comment: You should include the relevant code in your question itself. External links can go dead unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store connection object and do not close it... there is nothing special about that.
**In your code you are using try-with-resources and this causes connection to close**, as all closeables from try declaration are closed at the end of try-with-resources block.

```
            try (Connection connection = connectToSQLite(); // here, you are doing that inside try(), so it will be closed at the end of try block.
                 PreparedStatement preparedStatement =
                         connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from `dates` WHERE `uuid` =?")) {
                preparedStatement.setString(1, uuid);
                try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
                    consumer.accept(resultSet.next());
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
```

So if you will connect once in onEnable and then store that connection object in some variable you can just use it where you want to:

```
//field in class
private Connection connection;
//inside onEnable
connection = connectToSQLite();
//in other method:
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement =
                     connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from `dates` WHERE `uuid` =?")) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, uuid);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
                consumer.accept(resultSet.next());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

But note that connection might fail for many other reasons and you might need to reconnect, it might be good idea to use some pooling, there are libraries for that, like HikariCP, then you still "close" your connection, and you can (and should) still use try-with-resources but that connection from library instead of closing itself will just return to pool of connections.
It also allows you to use this connections in very simple way in multiple threads.

Comment: Then please upvote and accept this answer - you should always do this if someone helps you - as this is how stackoverflow works.